# git directory conflicts with remote repository

Tags: git, directory

I'm the sole man working on my project and I have a dev machine, a nas, and another machine. I work on my dev, push changes on my project to the remote repo on my nas, normally this works well, but now I made some directory changes and pushed them to the master branch on my nas. I again made some directory changes and wanted them again to push on my nas. So first I did a pull `git pull origin master` and that fails with:

`CONFLICT (rename/rename): Rename "svgopen/presentation/images/wine-problem.jpg"->"presentation/svgopen/images/wine-problem.jpg" in branch "HEAD" rename "svgopen/presentation/images/wine-problem.jpg"->"presentation/images/wine-problem.jpg" in "7fee244f7b93b0300783519870f2a8287ef6ace4"`

`git status`  shows:

```
#   added by them:      images/wine-problem.jpg
#   added by them:      images/wine-problem2.jpg
#   added by us:        svgopen/images/wine-problem.jpg
#   added by us:        svgopen/images/wine-problem2.jpg
```

Indicating the same images in an images directory which has been moved. Is there a way to convince git quickly that all additions 'by us' are the ones to be maintained? And 'by them' is rubbish and can be ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing a merge then you can use the following options: `git merge -s recursive -X ours`. This will automatically accept local changes as the correct ones in any conflict resolution.

Or, since you're the only man on the project you might just do a `git push --force` to force the remote repo to match your local copy.

Comment: I choose to do the git push --force, and manually removed all the files (with an emacs macro).

Answer (score 0):

If you're already in conflict then you can:

```
git checkout --ours file
```

See [this blog post for more details](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/25/keep-either-file-in-merge-conflicts.html)

Comment: I was in conflict with a remote repo so --ours was not working.

Comment: Except when you do that in these cases you get: error: path <file path / name > does not have our version